# C++ Mastermind For Loop

Tags: c++, loops

## Edit

I've included `#include <sstream>` now. This helped. But still an issue displaying the correct information. I've stepped it out, and it has to deal with some sort of program error. I have the text file already made inside of the same folder path. I've tried setting it to a direct C:/ path such as

*C:\Users\Matt\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\listofcolors.txt*

I'm having problem opening my file and displaying data. I recently downloaded Microsoft Visual Basic C++ to write the program I need for Mastermind. My goal is to create numbers that represent 9 to the 5th and put them within a text file. (Essentially, 5 columns of 9 numbers, 9 I've written this so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {    

    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int c = 0;
    int d = 0;
    int e = 0;
    std::string result;
    std::stringstream sstm;
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("listofcolors.txt");



    if (myfile.is_open())
    {

        for (a = 0; a<9; a++) {
            sstm << a << b << c << d << e;
            result = sstm.str();
            myfile << result << '\n';
            for (b = 0; b<9; b++) {
                sstm << a << b << c << d << e;
                result = sstm.str();
                myfile << result << '\n';
                for (c = 0; c<9; c++) {
                    sstm << a << b << c << d << e;
                    result = sstm.str();
                    myfile << result << '\n';
                    for (d = 0; d<9; d++) {
                        sstm << a << b << c << d << e;
                        result = sstm.str();
                        myfile << result << '\n';
                        for (e = 0; e<9; e++) {
                            sstm << a << b << c << d << e;
                            result = sstm.str();
                            myfile << result << '\n';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


            myfile.close();
            return 0;
        }
    }

    else cout << "Unable to open file";

    return 0;

}
```

For some reason, nothing is outputted. Any ideas??? Thank you!!

Comment: For heaven's sake give your variable meaningful names please.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Right --- so int a, represents position 1, or position a. b 2, c3, d4, e5. They're meaningful in the sense that they're alpha numeric.

Comment: I ran it through the debugger --- it said it was unable to find anything =/

Comment: ^ Debugger is not a magic tool.   You have to step it, step by step manually, and investigate what is happening in each step yourself.  You may try putting a break-point at some lines e.g. "int a = 0;".

Comment: You only need the innermost print, I think, and `myfile << a << b << c << d << e << '\n';` cuts out the middleman. Oh, and are you wanting to output 0-9 or 0-8?

Comment: I pasted the code into Visual Studio 2015, ran it, and it generated a listofcolors.text file. Are you sure it's really not doing so for you? Is the file perhaps in a parent directory from where you were expecting it?

Comment: @BlondeyGill _"I ran it through the debugger --- it said it was unable to find anything"_ Hmm, what please? The debugger usually doesn't tell you so. You step through your code an check if all values are in shape and expected.

Comment: @TheUndeadFish did it really work for you? I've tried a few online programs as well as using Visual Studio 2015... for some reason it's just not working -- no numbers are being input into the file and it says I'm unable to find the file specified for my Console Application

Comment: @BlondeyGill *what exactly* is saying it cant find *what* file? You need to be more specific. What is the actual error message verbatim? Is it a compiler error, a linker error, or a runtime error?

Comment: Thank you guys so much for responding to me and offering help. The errors had come from not having downloaded the debugging library (i.e. unable to load kernal32.dll), so the debugger wasn't working. It's been a while since touching C++, but now that I have built the project correctly -- it compiles without error. My code is wrong because it outputs the number strings on top of each other. ie.
00000
0000000000
000000000000000
00000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000

Ken Y-N's solution worked, appreciate ya guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can get clever by borrowing [this arbitrary base conversion code](http://www.strudel.org.uk/itoa/) that will output numbers in base 9 - see the [`cout` version online here](https://ideone.com/rabcxQ):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

/**
 * C++ version 0.4 std::string style "itoa":
 * Contributions from Stuart Lowe, Ray-Yuan Sheu,

 * Rodrigo de Salvo Braz, Luc Gallant, John Maloney
 * and Brian Hunt
 */
std::string itoa(int value, int base) {

    std::string buf;

    // check that the base if valid
    if (base < 2 || base > 16) return buf;

    enum { kMaxDigits = 35 };
    buf.reserve( kMaxDigits ); // Pre-allocate enough space.


    int quotient = value;

    // Translating number to string with base:
    do {
        buf += "0123456789abcdef"[ std::abs( quotient % base ) ];
        quotient /= base;
    } while ( quotient );

    // Append the negative sign
    if ( value < 0) buf += '-';

    std::reverse( buf.begin(), buf.end() );
    return buf;
}

int main() {    
    ofstream myfile("listofcolors.text");

    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9; i++)
        {
            // Formats the number to five places, filled with leading zeroes
            myfile << setw(5) << setfill('0') << itoa(i, 9) << '\n';
        }

        myfile.close();
    }
    else
        cout << "Unable to open file";

    return 0;
}
```

Note that the file is created in the working directory; here is [how to check and set where it is](https://codeyarns.com/2013/12/30/how-to-change-working-directory-in-visual-studio/).

Also note that your code had the `myfile.close()` inside the first loop, so it would only have printed from `00000` to `08888`.

Finally, since you are on Windows, use File Explorer to search for `listofcolors.txt`, just in case it is being created in an unexpected location.

Comment: Ken,

You're awesome thanks for sharing this. For Mastermind -- Although 88,888 (or in your case 99,999) is the right idea, we have to eliminate every option that includes the 9 value as there is only 9 different colors (0 through 8). That's why I built it with the for loops. I'm still struggling to make this work.. perhaps there is an error with how I installed visual basic I'm not sure, working on it.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, text files have a `.txt` file extension, not `.text`.  Also, you are creating the file using a relative path, so it will be created in the process's current working directory, which may not be what you are expecting it to be.  Always use absolute paths.

Your loop code is unnecessarily complex, it can be simplified to something more like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {    

    ofstream myfile("C:\\some path\\listofcolors.txt", ios_base::trunc);    

    if (myfile.is_open())
    {    
        for (int a = 0; a < 9; a++)
        for (int b = 0; b < 9; b++)
        for (int c = 0; c < 9; c++)
        for (int d = 0; d < 9; d++)
        for (int e = 0; e < 9; e++) {
            if (!(myfile << a << b << c << d << e << '\n')) {
                cout << "Unable to write to file";
                return 0;
            }
        }
        myfile.close();
        cout << "File created";
    }    
    else
        cout << "Unable to create file";

    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. This really helped, thank you Remy!